# Putting a user input into a print function on python

Tags: python, input

Program needs to generate random questions (with numbers 0-100). The code needs to check if users output is correct or incorrect. Text in bold = user input, example as follows

27 + 33 = **60**
correct
77 + 12 = **89**
incorrect

Comment: Good story, how are you supporting those statements?

Comment: Why is `77 + 12 = 89` incorrect? I'm tired, but not that tired.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

I 'll try to help you out

a) Make two numbers ( `num1` , `num2` ) with `random.randint`
b) Store user input in `answer`
c) Check if `num1` plus `num2` equals `answer`
d) Print the appropriate response

It's quite easy, you can solve this in 6 - 7 lines ( or less )

Comment: Anyone with half a brain when it comes to problem solving can figure this out. Stackoverflow is not a site where these questions are tolerated. OK answer to me nethertheless.